# Heroku website only loads slowly the first time, even after clearing local cache?

Tags: performance, debugging, heroku, dns, webserver

I have a website hosted on heroku. Whenever I load it for the first time after awhile (I haven't figured out the exact interval yet, be it days or hours), it takes upwards of 15 seconds to load. Subsequent loads are <1second, even if I clear the cache completely and open it in an incognito tab.

Why might this be? It almost seems like some kind of DNS issue but I haven't really got a clue. I don't know how to troubleshoot something like this. The situation seems to be the same even on other computers at other locations.

Comment: Are you running on a free Dyno ? Free dynos goes to sleep and have 30s wake-up duration.

Comment: Yeah you nailed it, that’s exactly the problem. Thanks so much. I didn’t even notice that in their documentation.

Comment: My app is under a hobby Dyno and it works fine. I only use the free web Dyno and free worker Dyno for the staging app.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the Heroku docs:

> If an app has a free web dyno, and that dyno receives no web traffic in a **30-minute** period, it will sleep.

When the dyno receives traffic again, it will take a few seconds to wake up, hence the delay you've experienced.

Note that the Heroku free tier also has a maximum number of dyno hours per month. A sleeping dyno doesn't use any hours, but it does when it's active. When the hours are used up, the dyno won't wake up to incoming traffic.

You can see your remaining quota of dyno hours with:

```sh
$ heroku ps -a <app name>
```

Heroku suggests upgrading to a hobby dyno if your app needs to be permanently accessible. More info on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours

Answer (score 0):

On the free tier, Heroku dynos go to sleep if they aren't used after an hour or something like that. They take a few seconds to wake up. Pay for the service and it stops happening, or write a script to ping your site every couple minutes or something.